# Net Core Web API 2.2 Protecting sensitive data

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-2.2

I am developing .Net Core Web API 2.2 project and trying to protect it best I can. This application will be connected to SQL database plus it will be sending emails from the server, and therefore I would like to figure out what is the good way of protecting my sensitive data (such as connection string, database password or even email password for SMTP account).

I have read that it is bad practice storing your passwords in a plain text in your file somewhere and one of the best practices is to use some **Microsoft Azure** functionality (where you provide some key and it returns you the actual password) that I have not yet used. Furthermore I do not have any subscription with Azure, and for the time being I would like not to go that direction.

Another method proposed by some of you guys was to store all the password to **Environmental Variables** and simply reference it in the application. I am currently exploring this option, as my app will be hosted on a 'virtual windows server' where I do not have direct access to, and thus it's difficult (without direct access) to get there and set up environmental variables (not even sure if that would be possible).

Finally, so far the best option (in case it will not be possible to use the variables mentioned above), was to actually store connections and passwords directly to **appsettings.json** file, but to hash them and decrypt on run-time. This option for me is surely feasible; however I wanted to ask (even though this might be quite subjective) you guys, whether this is a correct approach or there is something I have missed that could help me better to protect my application from external threats.

Any suggestions or advices would be more than appreciated as I do not really know now how to proceed.

P.S. I am using VSTS repository to store all the application code, which might be probably (I am guessing) the reason why people suggest to at least hash your passwords when storing them in **appsettings.json**

Comment: Hint: [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview). Best combined with [managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appsettings.json` file should never be used for secrets simply because it's committed to source control. That alone makes it a bad choice. However, there is also no capability to encrypt anything in `appsettings.json`. You could, I suppose, encrypt your secrets via some other means and merely place the ciphertext in `appsettings.json` manually after the fact, but then you would need some facility to decrypt the secret later, when then means exposing your means of encryption (i.e. your private key), which kind of defeats the entire point. Long and short, don't use `appsettings.json`.

Environment variables are a compromise solution. Since you manually set them on the server (not in your source control) and they can be made to only be accessible to certain users (restricted access), you get a modicum of security. However, they are also stored plaintext, which means if someone is able access the server to view them, all security is out the window. Environment variables can also be set as part of your CI\D pipeline in DevOps (formerly VSTS), so direct access to the server is not necessarily a prerequisite as long as the service account doing the deploy has the necessary access.

Azure Key Vault is the recommended approach because it's the only built-in config provider that supports encryption, meaning your secrets are encrypted at rest and pretty much secure end-to-end. However, there's nothing uniquely special about Azure Key Vault other than its ready availability. You can conceivably use any type of service that lets store secrets securely; you may just have to write your own config provider to target it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I do understand that Azure Key Vault is great option, however that requires subscription with Microsoft Azure that I currently don't have. Or is there possibility to use just this feature for free?

Comment: Not for free, but it's very minimal cost.

Comment: @ChrisPratt `appsettings.json` shouldn't be committed to source control.